# How to find next [ ] using shell script and comment all the lines between them?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to comment a set of lines using Shellscript.

```
$>cat abc.txt
[entry1]
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop

[entry2]
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qust

[entry3]
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
yz

[entry4]
...
...
...
...
```

from the above file, i want to find the [entry2] and comment all the lines between [entry2] to [entry3]
Note: The number of lines between entries are not same.

I want output like below..

```
$>cat abc.txt
[entry1]
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop

#[entry2]
#abcd
#efgh
#ijkl
#mnop
#qust

[entry3]
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
yz

[entry4]
...
...
...
...
```

I'm thinking that we can do this with sed. but not sure about exact usage.

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Post the expected output tooo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed, `sed` is your friend. You could match text in between pattern to achieve what you want.

```
sed -E '/^\[entry2\]/,/^$/s/^(.)/#\1/' file

[entry1]
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop

#[entry2]
#abcd
#efgh
#ijkl
#mnop
#qust

[entry3]
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
yz

[entry4]
...
...
...
...
```

---

**How it works**

- `/pattern1/,/pattern2/` matches text in between the patterns including the patterns
- The command that follows, `s` here is applied on all such lines.
- Now since you don't need need to comment blank lines we need to check the line for at least one non-blank character( Note the `.` which accomplishes this).
- The `^` matches the beginning of the line
- The `()` is used for grouping characters and `\1` is used in the replacement part to replace the groups
- Now read the lines together

---

**Note**

The `[]` has special meaning in sed, they represent character ranges. To search for a literal`[` or `]` you need to escape them - ie `\[` - as we've done here.

---

Comment: Hi sjsam, Included the correct file format again. Edited. Can you pls suggest now?

Comment: @SanthoshkumarRamachandran : See the update.. This assumes that there is blank line before each [entry] field.

Comment: Excellent sjsam.. I'm getting the output as expected. could you explain the command?

Comment: @SanthoshkumarRamachandran : see the last update, I notice that blank lines are not commented in the expected output, so changed the solution to fit that requirement

Comment: ++ you managed to get rid of comment on blank line above entry3 :)

Comment: @soFan : Perhaps, that would be an easy tweek in your awk solution too..

Comment: sed '/^\[entry2\]/,/^$/s/^/#/' 
if i'm not wrong, it searches for the pattern ^\[entry2\ & ^$ and subtitutes the #. 
sed 'find_this,find_that/substitute/lines_found/with#/'

please confirm.

Comment: @sjsam , I am lost, feel free to suggest or edit. :|

Comment: @sjsam, Great. Understood. Thank you so much.

Comment: Oops. I'm getting the below error..<br>
-bash-3.2$ sed -E '/^\[entry2\]/,/^$/s/^(.)/#\1/' abc.txt
sed: invalid option -- E

Comment: @SanthoshkumarRamachandran : Probably because you're sed doesn't support the `-E` option, use `-r` instead..

Comment: @SanthoshkumarRamachandran : Just curiosity, which `sed` version are you using?

Comment: @sjsam, Its 415 version.

Comment: @SanthoshkumarRamachandran : I see, what operating system and which sed build( I mean is it GNU sed?)

Comment: @sjsam, <br>sed version 4.1.5 <br>-bash-3.2$ cat /etc/*-release
Enterprise Linux Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Carthage)
Oracle Linux Server release 5.11
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk ' /^\[entry2\]/ {flag=1} /^\[entry3\]/{flag=0} flag { $0="#"$0}1' entry
[entry1]<br>
abcd<br>
efgh<br>
ijkl<br>
mnop<br><br>

#[entry2]<br>
#abcd<br>
#efgh<br>
#ijkl<br>
#mnop<br>
#qust<br><br>
#
[entry3]<br>
abcd<br>
efgh<br>
ijkl<br>
mnop<br>
qrst<br>
uvwx<br>
yz<br>

[entry4]
...
...
...
...
```

Comment: Hi soFan, added the expected output and the file format. pls check now and suggest

Comment: @SanthoshkumarRamachandran , check now if it helps

Comment: @soFan : Pls note that blank lines are not commented, you need to tweek the o/p a bit to achieve it.. ;)